# Listview custom adapter does not get the corresponding row data

Tags: android, listview, location

Hi I'm new here and I hope to contribute a lot with some questions and answers.

My problem is that I'm building an app that requieres a list with a custom adapter. This adapter gets the location of several objects and displays it on a field in the row, but when I scroll through the list the locations swap randomly.

This is my adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<myObject> implements ListAdapter {
    private double currentLongitude;
    private double currentLatitude;

    private Context context;
    private List<myObject> data;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView myObjectDistance;
        TextView myObjectName;
    }

    public LogSampleCellAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<myObject> data) {
        super (context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.myObjectName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_myObjectName);
            viewHolder.myObjectDistance = convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_myObjectDistance);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (data != null) {
            myObject obj = data.get(position);

            if (obj.getLatitude() == "" || obj.getLongitude() == "" || obj.getLatitude() == null || obj.getLongitude() == null)
                viewHolder.wellDistance.setText(R.string.no_available);
            else
                getLocation(viewHolder, well);

            viewHolder.myObjectName.setText(obj.getName());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private void getLocation (final ViewHolder viewHolder, final myObject obj) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Be sure to allow location services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context).requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_REQUEST, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    currentLongitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                    currentLatitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                    float[] results = new float[1];

                    android.location.Location.distanceBetween(Double.parseDouble(obj.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(obj.getLongitude()), currentLatitude, currentLongitude, results);
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

                    double miles = results[0] * 0.000621371192;

                    if (miles >= 1)
                        viewHolder.myObjectDistance.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(miles)) + " miles");
                    else
                        viewHolder.myObjectDistance.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(miles * 5280)) + " feet");

                }
            }, Looper.myLooper());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better not to pass viewHolder to thread in your case getLocation(). instead what you have to do is. You might need a minor tweak but this is the idea.

```
 private void getLocation (int position) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Be sure to allow location services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context).requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_REQUEST, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    currentLongitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                    currentLatitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                    float[] results = new float[1];

                    android.location.Location.distanceBetween(Double.parseDouble(obj.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(obj.getLongitude()), currentLatitude, currentLongitude, results);
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

                    double miles = results[0] * 0.000621371192;

                    myObject obj = data.get(position);
                    obj.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
                    obj.setLongitude(currentLongitude);
                    data.set(position,obj);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChaged();


                }
            }, Looper.myLooper());
        }
    }
```

There is many issues with your code, like asking for permission from listview adapter. Better to ask prior to it.

Comment: About the location permissions, how can I remove them from the adapter, because the if statement is required by the location services, or just suppress the lint? PD: I'm making sure the location services are on

According to the answer itself, my issue according to your answer is because I'm passing the viewholder to the loop

Comment: If the location permission is not granted by the user then is there any need to load the listview?

Comment: Yes, because there are items that might not have location at all

Comment: Try my answer and let me the result. you might need to do some tweaks.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you! Was the view holder on the loop